# ANTLR3: how to map the instructions in AST to line number in its java source file

Tags: antlr3

How to find the line numbers(of source file) of instructions from AST.

example:

for the following code

24> void foo(){

25>      System.out.println(" hi ");

26> }

the ast corresponding to print statement is

```
         METHOD_CALL
              .
                 .
                    System
                    out
                 println
              ARGUMENT_LIST
                 EXPR
                    " hi "
```

I want to retrieve the line number of "System" from the generated Tree. The answer for "System" should be 25(line number in the source code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Tree` for the `System` token is in fact a [`CommonTree`](http://antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/tree/CommonTree.html), then you can use the [`CommonTree.getToken()`](http://antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/tree/CommonTree.html#getToken%28%29) method to get the [`Token`](http://antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/Token.html) for `Symbol`. You can then call [`Token.getLine()`](http://antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/Token.html#getLine%28%29) to get the line number.

Comment: hi I tried it for the following input:                               "class HelloWorld{ \n
   \n
   public static void main(String args[]){ \n
        \n
 System.out.println("Hello world"); \n
        \n
   } \n
   \n
} "  where "\n" denotes new line. When I say Token.getLine() I get the output as 1, its same for every other instruction. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I was able to figured out the problem. I was using ANTLRStringStream in place of ANTLRFileStream. Thank you.